# Now that I have full Edit Privileges, can I find my old rejected edits and apply them?

Tags: discussion

One edit I remember was to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/what-are-the-various-methods-of-tuning-the-guitar) where I tried to make the tab better reflect the text.

I know I can just redo it now, but is there a list somewhere? Or are rejected edits utterly deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka.

https://music.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=all&tab=rejected

Answer (score 0):

They are probably stored somewhere in the database, but to my knowledge if an edit is rejected it disappears from the UI.

Comment: Inner Sanctum VooDoo. I get you. :)